# biztalk: identify message

Tags: biztalk

In my case, I need to parse a bunch of text files and search for a specific strings in each.  Each text file is formatted differently, so I can't create a generic flat file schema(or can I?).

Is there a way to simply parse the text in each file, and then use orchestration to make decisions based on the result of the search?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the formats?  Possibly you can create a generic schema if they were, for example, all CSV files with different contents.  However if they are totally different in delimiters then you probably can't use a generic schema and would have to write a custom pipeline component to probe the contents of the message so you can then publish them with promoted properties so you can then have Orchestrations subscribing to them and running them through pipelines with specific flat file disassembler with a schema for that message type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread answers my question

MSDN Forum: [Multiple flat files on single rcv location](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f94d1a9-215f-4f09-bd56-d01f51a61aca/multiple-flat-files-on-single-rcv-location?forum=biztalkgeneral), which recommended to use different receive locations and file masks to distinguish the different files